# Add row dynamically to table in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, system.web.ui.webcontrols

I'm trying to add rows dynamically to a System.Web.UI.WebControls.Table control in ASP.NET. I found some [sample code](http://forums.asp.net/t/1219583.aspx) that does what I'm seeking, but it only adds a single row.

It seems like the table row count does not carry from one page load to the next. The user should be able to add as many rows as desired, and I need to capture the data from each row.

What am I missing? Code below.

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" %>
<script runat="server">

    Sub btnAddEmail_Click(ByVal Sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

        Dim tr As New TableRow
        Dim tcLabel As New TableCell
        Dim tcTextBox As New TableCell
        Dim newLabel As New Label
        Dim newTextBox As New TextBox

        Dim i As Integer = Table1.Rows.Count + 1

        newLabel.ID = "Email" + Convert.ToString(i)
        newLabel.Text = "Email" + Convert.ToString(i)

        newTextBox.ID = "txtEmail" + Convert.ToString(i)

        tcLabel.Controls.Add(newLabel)
        tcTextBox.Controls.Add(newTextBox)

        tr.Cells.Add(tcLabel)
        tr.Cells.Add(tcTextBox)

        Table1.Rows.Add(tr)

    End Sub

</script>

<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:Button runat="server" Text="Add Email" ID="btnAddEmail"
        onclick="btnAddEmail_Click" />
    <asp:Table ID="Table1" runat="server">
        <asp:TableRow>
            <asp:TableCell>
                <asp:Label ID="Email1" runat="server" Text="Email1"></asp:Label></asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TableCell>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></asp:TableCell>
        </asp:TableRow>
    </asp:Table>
</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ASP.NET is stateless -- you need to persist any data you want between pages loads into a Session variable.

You'll need to store the DataTable/DataSet in a session variable, and assign the Datasource property of Table1 to that DataSet in your "PageLoad" event. Then, in your "Click" event, add the row to the DataSet in your Session variable.

**update**

You maybe able to set `ViewState="true"` on the control you wish to have persist data through postbacks.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful, but I do not yet have the "reputation" to vote up the answer.  :)  I was hoping there was a simple way to say, "Maintain the number of rows in this table and the data within upon postback." Some kind of config option like AutoEventWireup=True, although I realize that relates to event handlers. I'm using this for an extremely simple page.